# What exactly does 'Bash@3' mean?

Tags: bash, yaml

I see `- task: Bash@3` near the top of practically every YAML template for a Bash task, however, I don't know what that specifically means/what it is telling us (specifically the `@3` part).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "*Yes, it represents the task version. More precisely, the major version.*"